# HTTP request from SQL Server closing connection after processing 248 messages

Tags: sql-server, ole-automation

I had a stored procedure which raises connection to a webservice and load the results back into the table. The input BODY for the http request is in a column IP_BODY. I use another stored procedure which loops the webservice stored procedure for all the values in the table.

I'm noticing that after 248 messages processed, my SQL server was not able to raise a HTTP connection with the webservice. Any such limits exists which restricts the number of messages being processed ?

Comment: Basically the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638910/sql-ole-automation-call-limit). Short answer - don't use ole automation, use CLR if you must do it in sql.

Comment: Ole procedures are basically deprecated, they are difficult to use, error-prone and have numerous limitations. You should really do this kind of thing from Powershell, C# etc